# Calculate big O complexity of partitioning problem

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, partitioning

My pseudo-code looks like:

```
solve(n)
    for i:= 1 to n do
       process(i);
       solve(n-i);
```

where `process(n)` is a function with some complexity `f(n)`. In my case `f(n)=O(n^2)`, but I am also interested in general case (for example if `f(n)=O(n)`).

So, I have `T(n) = f(n) + ... + f(1) + T(n-1) + ... + T(1)`. I cannot apply Master theorem as the sub-problems are not the same size.

*How to calculate complexity of this recursion?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small trick – consider `solve(n-1)`:

```
solve(n)  :  T(n)   =  f(n) + f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... + f(1) + T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(0)
solve(n-1):  T(n-1) =         f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... + f(1) +          T(n-2) + ... + T(0)
```

Subtract the latter from the former:

[image]

Expand repeatedly:

[image]

Solve the last summation for `f(n)` to obtain the complexity.

e.g. for `f(n) = O(n)`:

[image]

---

Alternative method – variable substitution:

[image]

`S(m)` is in the correct form for the Master Theorem.

e.g. for `f(n) = O(n) = O(log m)`, use Case 2 with `k = 0`:

[image]

Same result, q.e.d.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I think that there is one mistake, the sum of `i*2^i` is equal `n2^n` not `n2^n+2(2^n-1)`. Right? Anyway, this doesn't change overall complexity.

Comment: @Dejan I did make a typo there (should be - not + – will edit to correct), but the sum is [definitely not just equal to `n2^n`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+x*2%5Ex+from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+n+-+1).